# Prove that ${(1-p+pe^t)}^n = E(e^{t\sum Z_i}))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

Let $Z_1,...,Z_n$ be independent random variables such that $ Z_i \in \vert0,1\vert$. Prove that ${(1-p+pe^t)}^n = E(e^{t\sum Z_i}))$ where $p=\sum{\frac{E(Z_i)}{n}}$

Not quite sure how to do this. Do I write out the formula (as a summation) for $E(e^{tZ_i})$ and then use Taylor series to get bounds on $e^{tZ_i}$ maybe? I just don't see it at the moment. AM-GM??

would like some help

Comment: If we take $n=$ and let $Z = {1 \over 2}$ ae., then the left hand side is ${1 \over 2}(1+e^t)$ but the right hand side is $e^{t \over 2}$.

Comment: Did you mean $Z_i \in \{0,1\}$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Independence of the $Z_i$ (hence also of the $e^{tZ_i}$) says:
$$\mathbb E(e^{t\sum Z_i})=\mathbb E(e^{tZ_1})\times\cdots\times\mathbb E(e^{tZ_n})$$
If the $Z_i$ are identically distributed then this leads to:$$\mathbb E(e^{t\sum Z_i})=\mathbb E(e^{tZ_1})^n$$Also note that here: $$p=\mathbb E(Z_1)$$

Comment: Thank you for the help but why is it the case that $E(e^{tZ_i})=1-p+pe^{t}$ though? In fact why does $p=E(Z_1)$?

Comment: The $Z_i$ are independent, the question didn't state identical...

Comment: @copper.hat. Indeed. That's why I started there with 'if...'.

Comment: If the $Z_i$ have the same distribution then $\sum E(Z_i)=n\times E(Z_1)$ because $E(Z_i)=E(Z_1)$ for each $i$. This leads to $p=E(Z_1)$. You don't really mention that the $Z_i$ indeed have the same distribution. Neither do you mention what distribution. The only thing you mention is that the $Z_i$ take values in $[0,1]$. That's why I did not say anything about that.